# Where does the extra "1" in this output come from?

Tags: ruby, output

I have a simple code that produces a times table:

```
def times_table(rows)
  columns = rows
  1.upto(rows) do |x|
    1.upto(columns) do |y|
      printf "%5d", x*y
    end
    print "\n"
  end
end
```

When I try to place this in a file "codetester.rb" followed by the line `puts times_table(4)`, I get the following result:

```
$ ruby codetester.rb 

  1    2    3    4
  2    4    6    8
  3    6    9   12
  4    8   12   16
1
```

Where is the extra '1' at the end coming from, and (cute as it is) how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To fix this without changing your method body, don't call `puts` and only use:

```
 times_table(4)
```

You're getting the extra `1` because you wrote:

```
puts times_table(4)
```

This says, "print the value of `times_table(4)`". The value of this is "1", because the return value of `times_table(4)` is equal to:

```
1.upto(rows) { ... }
```

and `upto` returns the value of what it was called on.

---

Here's a simpler, analogous example, since OP seems a little confused about how return values work.

Let's say you had this method:

```
def foo
  puts "hello!"
  100
end
```

If you do this:

```
foo
```

then "hello!" will be printed as a side effect of calling `foo`. The return value of 100 is not printed, because you didn't print the value of `foo` itself. So you will see:

```
hello!
```

as the output.

By contrast, if you do this:

```
puts foo
```

then "hello!" will be printed as a side effect of calling `foo`, as before. But this time, the return value is also printed, because you wrote `puts foo`. So you will see:

```
hello!
100
```

as the output.

Comment: So the method call 'puts times_table(4)' executes the code in the method, and then ALSO returns the value of the object "times_table(4)"? Or is the printing of the 4x4 table just a side effect of the interpreter returning this value '1'? In other words, how did one method call invoke two different events?

Comment: @pgblu I added another example to clarify. Hopefully that resolves any misunderstandings.